# Xcode Internal Error while upgrading the project

Tags: iphone

While working with project I upgraded the version of IOS SDK 3.2 to 4.2 
I don't know what to do, please help me out.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use source control?  If so roll back to a prior version of the project.pbxproj file and try again.

If not, you should have.  Even single developers should use source control, and with Git integration in XCode 4 there is no excuse not to.

One side thought along those lines is - do you use Time Machine?  If so, use that to restore your whole project after copying off the current version elsewhere.  That can be your last-ditch version control even if you don't use anything else.

Now that the mandatory chiding is out of the way, let me actually help you.

The error sure looks like it's unhappy with your current target. So try editing the project.pbxproj file, and totally removing that target by hand.  The file is in XML, you should be able to figure out where the target definition is.  While you are in there you could even see if anything looks odd about the build target and fix that first.

With the target gone, try re-loading the project.

If that fails to work, it's actually not too hard to re-create a project from scratch.  Create a new target with the same name and starting project template.  Then copy over all of your current files (except the broken project file) replacing the ones the new project generated, and then drag and add all of your classes/images/xib files into the new project.